# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-api, undefined, translate

I'm trying to use Google Translate to translate text from a text box in javascript. I don't want to translate my entire web page but just the text within the text box.

this is my error:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined'

this is my code:

```
function translate(lang) {
  var text = document.getElementById('textArea').value
  google.load('language', '1');
  function initialize(text) {
    google.language.translate(text, 'en', 'es', function (result) {
      var translated = document.getElementById('textArea2');
      if (result.translation) {
        translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
      }
    });
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize(text));
}
```

Comment: have you added the google translate script in the `HTML`?

Comment: `google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize(text))` you are calling your callback function immediately instead of passing it, eg `setOnLoadCallback(initialize)`, or if you want to pass in the value `setOnLoadCallback(()=>initialize(text))`